# references for learning about branch cuts/ branch points in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Are there any good books/online resources for learning about branch cuts at the level of  introductory undergraduate complex analysis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I was an undergrad I really enjoyed [Palka's treatment of this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038797427X); it is definitely accessible and rigorous.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Will check it out.

Answer (score 5):

See http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~nair/abel.pdf It actually doesn't require any complex analysis really, but it explains branch cuts and points for Riemann surfaces of polynomials, so it's a great introduction. It also uses these to prove an important theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference.

Comment: Yayaya! Cool reference. +1!

Comment: @Davidac897 this link is not working.

Answer (score 5):

> I recommend to go through chapter *VI: Multifunctions* and chapter *VII: The Logarithmic Function* of *[Visual Complex Analysis](http://static.ow.ly/docs/needham_t_visual_complex_analysis_bhj.pdf)* by *T. Needham*.
>
> The sections
>
> - VI.1 Example: Fractional  powers, VI.2 Single-Valued Branches of a Multifunction, VI.3 Relevance to Power Series, VI.4 An Example with Two Branch Points
>
>   and
> - VII.1 Inverse of the Exponential Function, VII.2 The Logarithmic Power Series, VII.3 General Powers
>
> provide a guided tour regarding branch cuts and related aspects with plenty of illuminating pictures.