# Whether derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ only?

Tags: integration

Whether derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x>0$ only? Can't we write $$\frac{d}{dx} {\ln|x|} = \frac{1}{x} $$ so that we can get the corresponding integration formula for $\frac{1}{x}$ easily as $$\ln|x|$$
I have gone thorough this but it discusses only about integration [Is the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ equal to $\ln(x)$ or $\ln(|x|)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234624/is-the-integral-of-1-x-equal-to-lnx-or-lnx?newreg=d0a4dfffd037497db61691814c67a80b)

Comment: Are you asking about derivative or primitive? 'Cos if you are asking about the derivative of $x\mapsto\log(x)$ when $x\lt0$, what is $\log(-4)$?

Comment: You don't need to worry about $x=0$ since $\ln 0$ doesn't exist (since $e^y=0$ has no solution) -- at least in your situation, I expect.

Answer (score 1):

for $x>0$ $\frac{d}{dx}\ln |x|=\frac{d}{dx}\ln x=\frac{1}{x}$

for $x<0$ $\frac{d}{dx}\ln |x|=\frac{d}{dx}\ln (-x)=\frac{1}{-x}\times \frac{d}{dx}(-x)=\frac{1}{-x}\times (-1)=\frac{1}{x} $

Therefore $\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\ln |x|+C,  x \ne 0$

Comment: In the second step in  $$\frac{d}{dx}\ln (-x)=\frac{1}{-x}\times \frac{d}{dx}(-x) $$your (-x) is positive, that is what I want to ask whether  derivative of ln(x) is 1/x for x>0 only?

Comment: The derivative of $\ln x$ is $1/x$ for $x>0$ only because $\ln x$ is defined for $x>0$ only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to split the case whether $x$ is greater than zero or it is lower.

The reason is that you could deal with different integration constant. So the steps you have to go through are:

- Find the range of $x$
- If the range is all within positive/negative number, thus you can apply $\frac{d}{dx}\ln|x|=\frac{1}{x}.$ Otherwise you have to split the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ we have $\bigl(\ln|x|\bigr)'=\bigr(\ln(\sqrt{x^2})\bigr)'=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2}}\cdot2x=\dfrac{x}{|x|^2}=\dfrac{x}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{x}$.