# Find $f$ if $f'(x)=\dfrac{x^2-1}{x}$ knowing that $f(1) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $f(-1) = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I am asked the following problem:

> Find $f$ if $$f'(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x}$$

I am not sure about my solution, which I will describe below:

**My solution:**

The first thing that I've done is separate the terms of $f'(x)$

\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\frac{x^2-1}{x}\\
&=x-\frac{1}{x}\\
\therefore  \quad f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln|x|+c
\end{align*}

For ( x > 0 ):

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln x+c\\
f(1)&=\frac{1^2}{2}-\ln 1+c=\frac{1}{2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad c=0\\
f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln |x|
\end{align*}

For ( x < 0 )

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln (-x)+c\\
f(-1)&=\frac{(-1)^2}{2}-\ln [-(-1)]+c=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad c=-\frac{1}{2}\\
f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{2}-\ln |x|-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Is my solution correct? Should I really find two different answers, one for $x > 0$ and another for $x < 0$?

Thank you.

Comment: yes your solution is fine. As the domain has two connected components there can indeed be different constants of integration on each of them.

Comment: It looks fine to me. +1

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234624/is-the-integral-of-frac1x-equal-to-lnx-or-lnx (see the accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine! However a little typo when calculate $f(-1)=0$ not $-1$